# Image in HTML not getting aligned properly on converting to PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, html-to-pdf

I'm using itextsharp to convert my html portion to pdf. Everything is ok but the image always getting aligned left after converting html to pdf

```
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.uaa.alaska.edu/institutionaleffectiveness/Graduation/images/report_1.jpg" width="120"></div>
```

C# code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
pnlCertificate.RenderControl(hw);
src = sw.ToString();
AbsolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
src = src.Replace("src=\"/", string.Format("src=\"{0}", AbsolutePath));
StringReader sr = new StringReader(src);
Document pdfDoc = new Document();
pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(path + "/" + _CertificatesEntityCollection.First().Name + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: HTMLWorker has been deprecated for quite some time now. Please use XMLWorker: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/

Comment: I tried using XMLWorker but it didnt help. Still my image was aligning left. Finally I found GemBox Document. It works good. But, they will allow only 20 paragraphs of conversion free of cost, it was more than enough for my project.

Answer (score 0):

ITextSharp does not support Div tag so make use of table

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img src="http://www.uaa.alaska.edu/institutionaleffectiveness/Graduation/images/report_1.jpg" width="120">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in gsp pages. Hope it helps

```css
<div align="center">
    <p>
        <img src="http://www.uaa.alaska.edu/institutionaleffectiveness/Graduation/images/report_1.jpg" width="120">
    </p>
</div>
```